# Do I need to saw off excess for timber posts and fence spike DIY?

Tags: fence, gardening

First off - this is NOT A PRODUCT REVIEW

1. I have a leaning fence problem, and I want to fix it myself - fast.
2. I wanted to buy a timber pole (100x100mm) and a spike support (100x100mm) to solidify it

Here are the products I am going to buy

1. https://www.wickes.co.uk/Incised-Timber-Fence-Post-100-x-100mm-x-2-4m/p/540991
2. https://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Wedge-750mm-Support-Spike-for-Fence-Posts---100-x-100mm/p/540564

My question is - can I avoid not using a saw to trim any excess off of the timber? Or, is it worth just getting them?

Comment: Excess timber or anything is too much to fit in a certain space.  If you can move/make the certain space bigger, then you do not have excess.

Comment: **1)** "can I avoid not using a saw to trim any excess off". You may want to revisit this... It's _extremely_ unclear. **2)** "saw off excess for timber posts" What excess would need to be trimmed off? Maybe a drawing or picture would clarify things. **3)** "is it worth just getting them?" What are "them"? **4)** "is it worth just getting them?" is asking for opinions - different things have different values and worth to different people and we don't know your values and how you assign worth.

Comment: Do not need to cut a long fence post down to make it shorter, but usually looks better if the fence is not that high.  Usually that length of post is place in a hole in the ground, so it does not need cutting.  With those spikes you might cut one post in half and get two posts.

Comment: If you want to replace your leaning fence post with the spike the fence will go horizontal with the first windy day. It is not clear how you want to support the leaning fence but cutting off excess always looks better unless there are decorative caps on the posts